# QSpinBox в режиме disabled(true) оставить без серой заглушки

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Есть `QSpinBox * sum;`. Условие следующие: значения нельзя редактировать, значение нельзя выделять мышкой. Если использовать метод `sum->setDisabled(true);`, то мы получаем нужное, но при этом `QSpinBox` окрашен серым цветом. Как можно получить вышеперечисленное без окраски `QSpinBox` в серый цвет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно убрать заливку через установку параметров палитры:

```
QSpinBox sbox;
sbox.setDisabled(true);

QPalette p = sbox.palette();
p.setBrush(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Base
    , p.brush(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base));

sbox.setPalette(p);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я пробовал через setStyleShit(); но это работает с lineEdit, а со Spinbox не катит. В чем может быть разница?

Comment: @Madisson, уточните, не работает в моём ответе код для `QSpinBox` или Вы про `QWidget::setStyleSheet()`?

Comment: QWidget::setStyleSheet()